# Icon groups in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, menu

I am trying to put some icons into groups in the Xubuntu 14.04 menu.  I can do this no problem for applications I have installed myself (like Wine applications) but I seem to be unable to do so for system applications.

What I am trying to do is put the Settings Editor and Settings Manager icons into the "System" group in the menu, but no matter how many changes I make to the .desktop files in /usr/share/applications, the icons do not appear.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install `alacarte` and use it to enable the desired menus.